# How bind enum to combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-2.0

I need bind enum to combobox, **but** I need not all values

```
this.combobox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(RoleUser));

public enum RoleUser { Guest = 0, Student = 1, Instructor, Administrator };
```

How do this?

Don't use linq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) LINQ extension method for this:

```
Enum.GetValues (typeof(RoleUser)).Cast<RoleUser>().Except (new [] { RoleUser.Guest, RoleUser.Administrator });
```

Answer (score 1):

With out using  linq,you can put the returned value from Getvalues to an array and iterate on it to filter array then assign new created array to datasource